# mysql: most efficient way to select top n records by group

Tags: mysql

There are several good entries about how to select min/max or top n records by group using Mysql. My approach is admittedly pedestrian (I understand it), but I was wondering whether there's a better way that is still intuitively clear to me. One particularly ugly bit is the need to hard-code the counts required (1000) since one can't `set LIMIT_value := 1000;` and use it as parameter in the query.

So my question is: is there a better, less laborious way to select 1000 records from given segments? Bonus question (this can be processed via sed and piped into mysql...) Can I parameterize the 1000-records request?

Quick background: I'm looking at two customer cohorts that were given two different offer prices, but not properly randomized. I'm running the analysis on followup activity given different offer price levels.

I'm randomly matching customers (one cust. from first cohort with one cust. from the second cohort by grouping) using recency (R, 12m since last purchase, or more that 12m) and frequency (F, 1 time buyer, or 2x+) groupings to control for different potential customer segments unknown at the time of the marketing campaign. For those customers identified to be new-to-file at the time of the contact, both R and F values are 'NA', and constitute another grouping level. Thanks.

```
/* _lp_stp: low price sample, _hp_stp: high price sample */

drop table if exists _lp_stp;
create table _lp_stp as
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='2x+' limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='2x+' limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _lp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='2x+' limit 1000);


drop table if exists _hp_stp;
create table _hp_stp as
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='NA'   and fbin='2x+' limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m'  and fbin='2x+' limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='NA'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='1x'  limit 1000)
union
(select ID,price,rbin,fbin from _hp where rbin='12m+' and fbin='2x+' limit 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The query is only meant to look simpler, but performance likely to be poor,especially if you are dealing with big tables. And never-ever I want such query in my production DB,

```
select ID,price,rbin,fbin 
from _lp
inner join (
select substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(id order by id asc),",", 1000),",",-1) as id, fbin, rbin
where fbin in (...) and rbin in (...)
group by fbin, rbin
where rbin='12m+' and fbin='2x+' ) as t 
on t.rbin = _lp.rbin and t.fbin = _lp.fbin and t.rbin <= _lp.id
```

A little explanation of the query:

1. Subquery gets the id of the 1000th id in ascending order. For example, if you have 5000 records, subquery gives 4000 if grouping is not given( I have added an extra group by to fit each group)
2. Outer query gets then fetches all records who has value less than given record

Comment: Thanks cjg. I'll have to carefully step through your code as it isn't intuitive to me. I'll definitely follow-up.